# Prevent merge on master branch for a type of file - Git

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch

I have a git repo with a release branch ("master") and some other branches for develop purposes.

Being an embedded project, there are some .tbl files which are generated or modified on every compilation. I need to keep the tbl files in the master branch not modified (unless there is a new release) and therefore prevent merging with other branches from modifying those tbl files.

I already tried declaring tbl files as binary or using `*.tbl merge=ours` but as specified in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge this only work in case of conflict.

Has anyone ever run across a similar situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `*.tbl merge=ours` in `.gitattributes` file,
and add global setting:

```
git config --global merge.ours.driver true
```

It only keep the version of `*.tbl` file on `master` branch for part of situations (as the first two situations as below).

When you merge other branches into `master`, there has three situations for the `*.tbl` file:

- **Has conflict for the `*.tbl` file when merging:** that means the version of `*.tbl` file in other branches is different from the version in `master` branch. Since you have set merge strategies for the `*.tbl` as ours. Then the version of `*.tbl` on `master` branch will be kept.
- **Did not change the `*.tbl` file on both sides:** that means both the versions of `*.tbl` file on `master` the other branches are same, so don’t worry the `*.tbl` file on `master` branch is overwritten.
- **Change the `*.tbl` file only on other branches side:** this will overwrite the `*.tbl` file with the version of the other branches since git merge use the recursive merge strategy. So you need to switch `*.tbl` file with the version on `master` branch. So you can use below commands:

  ```
    git merge branchname
    git checkout HEAD~ *.tbl
    git commit -m 'switch the file as the version on master'
  ```

BTW, if the `*.tbl` file is not necessary to version control on non-master branches, you can only manage the file on `master` branch.

---

Or there is another option you can refer: **manage the file `*.tbl` in a separate branch** (such `tbl` branch).

Even the `*.tbl` file may be overwritten on `master` branch, the version on `tbl` branch should be correct. When you need a new release, you can checkout the version from `tbl` branch to `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
git checkout tbl *.tbl 
git commit -m 'recovery the version as last release'
```

Then you can prepare for the new release.

After releasing on `master` branch you can update the file on `tbl` branch:

```
git checkout tbl
git checkout master *.tbl
git commit -m 'update the file with new release version on tbl branch'
```

Comment: Actually that's not entirely true, because there is a third situation: if I modify the .tbl file only in the develop branch and then I merge that branch on the master one, I'll get no conflicts but my tbl get the changes from the develop branch.

Comment: `git merge -s ours` is not quite right either: it tells Git to *completely ignore* the other branch. That's fine for the `*.tbl` files, but presumably any *other* files should be merged.

Comment: I updated my answer, and for the situation the `*.tbl` file only changed on other branches, it need additional steps to switch the files to the original version on `master` branch.

Comment: About the "BTW" you added: is there a way to manage the file only in the master branch (something like a customized .gitignore which ignore *.tbl files everywhere except in master)?

Comment: So do you always need to create branches from `master` branch? If yes, you should delete the `*.tbl` files manually on the branches.

Comment: Even if I do this, every time I compile (for debugging of testing new features) I'll get a new tbl which could then be committed and eventually merged back into master. And I don't want this beacuse that would cause a mismatch between the release version of the tbl and the tbl other components are actually referring to. Sorry if this is a bit complicated

Comment: I added another option in the end of my answer. If it meet your situation, you can have a try.

Answer (score 1):

Git has no merge strategy for this case.

Short of writing your own merge strategy—`git merge -s ArenaLor` will invoke `git-merge-ArenaLor`, and you'd have to *write* that command but then it would do whatever *you* wanted—there is, as you observed, no way to get Git to do a normal three-way merge on most files but to always keep a particular version of a particular set of files in place.

Fundamentally, most merge strategies do the following:

1. Identify the merge-base commit.  Let's call this commit *B* for convenience.  *B* has a bunch of files saved as snapshots; from here, the other two branches diverge.
2. Diff the merge base against each branch tip, to find which files are changed in which branches.  For illustration, it's simplest to call the two branch tips *L* and *R*, for Left and Right, or Local and Remote, or Ours and Theirs (there is no *L* in the word "ours" but this is how Git works with the usual recursive and resolve strategies).
3. Build the new commit-to-make by taking each file from *B* (no change in either branch), *L* (file is changed only in our local/left-side branch), *R* (file is changed only in their remote/right-side branch), or—if the file is changed in *both* of the two branch-tip commits—by *combining* the changes.

The `*.tbl merge=ours` option in a `.gitattributes` file affects *only* step 3, and then *only* if the file is changed in *both* branch-tip commits.  That is, a *merge driver* is only run if Git has to *combine changes*.  It doesn't matter whether the changes have conflicts; what matters is that both *L* and *R* have changed some file *F* with respect to what was in the merge base commit *B*.

These decisions are all made by the merge strategy, though, so if you write your own, you can make your own decisions.  Note that the `-s ours` strategy is quite different: instead of doing the above three steps, it does this one step:

1. Take all the files from *L*.  We don't even need to find *B*, or look at the contents of *R*.  Just keep whatever's in the index right now and make a merge commit with parent 1 = *L* and parent 2 = *R*.

That does what you want for your `*.tbl` files, but is wrong for all your other files, so it's not suitable here.

Comment: So there is no way to get what I want, except maybe for writing my own merge strategy.

Comment: Right. The usual approach for the kind of file you're talking about here is not to commit it at all: commit, instead, some kind of "sample" or "default" (configuration) file and convert it to the target file that is then an untracked file (which may be added to `.gitignore` as well to stop Git from griping about it).

Comment: Me and my teammates thought about doing something like what you said but our conclusion is that it can't work. Our situation is: every time we compile our embedded OS, the tbl get changed; there is then a number of other components which depend on the tbl when compiling. So if I have an invalid tbl (maybe because I'm trying something new in the OS) and I try to compile a component to push it to release, that component will be invalid and not recognised by the OS.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like these `*.tbl` files should not be version-controlled by this repository at all. They're not related to the source, they are related instead to the OS. The control for these `*.tbl` files should be the target OS, not the thing you're building.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but I think you misunderstood; our project is made of an embedded OS (developed by us) and some "plugins" which rely on the tbl made by the OS when the are compiled. The problem is: plugins are actively release (like everyday), and between an OS release and another the tbl must be the same. But at the same time, we need to work, develop, debug the OS so we recompile it pretty often and there is the risk that an invalid tbl get merged into the `master` branch. I know this is getting complicated but we would like a supported solution instead of just be careful.

Comment: Regardless of how the integration itself happens, it still seems like the logical split point is "OS repository controls `*.tbl` files; plugins *use* (but do not source control) `*.tbl` files". Your full build is then assembled from at least two such repositories.